# When can a quadratic algorithm be better than an logarithmic one?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

As in when there are two algorithms that solve the same problem, one being quadratic and one being logarithmic, what context would mean it would be preferable to use the quadratic one, despite the implicit detriments.

Comment: Of the top of my head, I can't think of two algorithms for the same purpose which are quadratic and logarithmic.

Comment: @Schwern What about sorting algorithms, like Merge sort and Bubblesort? Bubblesort performs better on small inputs.

Comment: @AndrewVershinin Logarithmic time is O(logn) not O(nlogn). The question is about O(logn) vs O(n^k).

Comment: @Schwern Thanks, I messed those up! Practically speaking, I, too, can't remember two different, but valid algorithms for a task with these complexities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quadratic algorithm can be better up to a certain point, if the logarithmic one has a significantly larger constant, for example: first algorithm performs `1000 * logN` operations (exactly - for simplicity), and another one - `3 * N^2`. Then, up to about `N = 20`, the quadratic algorithm will perform better.